# Is there any way to make many panels in one webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm new to C#, ASP.NET, i'm using Visual Studio 2017.

I created a web shop with a SQL database and Entity Framework. I have a Panel in my form inside a `<section>` tag that retrive all products from DB in to the Panel.

Now I want to duplicate this `<section>` tag to include the Panel for each product type.  I have already created the method to get the product by type,
so finally I'll have the section with product for each product model in my form.

This is my code:

```
<section class="product-carousel">
    <!-- Heading Starts -->
    <h2 class="product-head">Latest Products</h2>
    <!-- Heading Ends -->
    <!-- Products Row Starts -->
    <div class="row">
      <asp:Panel ID="pnlProducts1" runat="server" CssClass="IndexPanelProduct"></asp:Panel>
     </div>
    <!-- Products Row Ends -->
</section>
<!-- Latest Products Ends -->
```

Code Behind

```
private void FillPage(int type)
{
    ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
    List<Product> products = productModel.GetProductByType(type);
    
        if (products != null)
        {
            foreach (Product product in products)
            {
                Panel productPanel1 = new Panel();
                ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton();
                Label lblShortDesc = new Label();
                Label lblbuysCount = new Label();
                Label lblNewPrice = new Label();
                Label lblOldPrice = new Label();

                imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/Images/product-images/" + product.Image;
                imageButton.CssClass = "productImage";
                imageButton.PostBackUrl = "~/Product_page.aspx?id=" + product.Id;

                lblShortDesc.Text = product.Name;
                lblShortDesc.CssClass = "mainProductDesc";

                lblbuysCount.Text = "Buys 120 +";
                lblbuysCount.CssClass = "mainProductBuys";


                lblNewPrice.Text = "Only for: $ " + product.NewPrice;
                lblNewPrice.CssClass = "mainProductprice";

                productPanel1.Controls.Add(imageButton);
                productPanel1.Controls.Add(lblShortDesc);
                productPanel1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<br />" });
                productPanel1.Controls.Add(lblNewPrice);
                productPanel1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<br />" });
                productPanel1.Controls.Add(lblNewPrice);
                productPanel1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<br />" });
                productPanel1.Controls.Add(lblbuysCount);

                pnlProducts1.Controls.Add(productPanel1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            pnlProducts1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "No Product Found !" });
        }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code detailing what you have attempted.  With that additional information, others might be in a better equipped to answer your question.

Comment: yes you can have many panels in one web page

Comment: If you're new to C# and ASP.NET then you probably should avoid WebForms (`*.aspx`, `<asp:Form runat="server">`, etc) entirely: it's an old, obsolete, and horribly broken web-framework that Microsoft first shipped in 2001 and discontinued in 2008. Why aren't you learning ASP.NET Core instead?

Comment: Okay so I'm not disagreeing with @Dai (MVC is your friend here rather than webforms), but I'll try support you anyway.  Do you wish the structure to be like this: `<div class="row"> <section>  <asp:Panel />`.  I mean a `section` for each product?

Comment: ...or do you wish for `FillPage()` to create a `section` first for each product, then place everything inside it?